# Open two months in datepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

i am using bootstrap datepicker. I want to open two months in one input. Current month and next month.

Here is some web pages :

https://www.kayak.de/flights

https://www.turna.com/

```
<input class="form-control date-picker-start" placeholder="Başlangıç Tarihi" type="text">

$('.date-picker-start').datepicker({
                format: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
                autoclose : true
            }).on('changeDate',function(e){
                //on change of date on start datepicker, set end datepicker's date
                $('.date-picker-end').datepicker('setStartDate',e.date)
            });
```

Is there any parameter which i use, for this, in bootstrap-datepicker.

Comment: Haven't a clue what you're asking us to do. If you are asking us to write the code for you, you're in the wrong place.

Comment: @Rob i just want to learn parameter of this in bootstrap-datepicker, if it exists. Or any method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished by setting the `numberOfMonths`.

```js
$('.date-picker-start').datepicker({
    format: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    autoclose : true
}).on('changeDate',function(e){
    //on change of date on start datepicker, set end datepicker's date
    $('.date-picker-end').datepicker('setStartDate',e.date)
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input class="date-picker-start" data-provide="datepicker">
```